# How to combine the {} and () operators correctly in regex?

Tags: regex

Regex

Objective:
I need to construct a regular expression that will allow me to extract a phone number that is being separated by odd things in odd places, and at the same time to avoid capturing/matching other things in the text. Example:

- `854-123-5234`
- `24/25229999`
- `23./4-4234344`
- `2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442`

There are the two groups.

1) Number

2) Separators

I could do `/((\d)|( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.))/` but the text will have 7 things from the number group and 0 to infinity from the separators group. I tried many things, but I am not getting anywhere.

This does not seem to work
`/(\d){7}( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\1|\2)*/`

And the problem here is that the back reference to the first group has to match to the exact same digit.

I am looking for a more elegant way of doing the following, the ***functionality/behavior should be the same exact as this expression***:

`/(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)( |\-|\(|\)|\/|\.)*(\d)/`

I am trying to figure out the short hand of the above. If anybody can provide me with advice/tips/assistance that would be great. The separators would also have to be a passive group since I do not care for them, but I think I can figure out that part.

Comment: What you are trying to do is very unclear, can you show the expected result for the strings you gave?

Comment: Please review help for how to ask a question, and how to provide examples of what you need.

Comment: I believe that the simplest way to go will be to use a regex to remove all the allowed delimiters, validate that the rest of the input is digits only and check that the number of digits is valid. The first two items can be done with simple regex - no need to go wild like you did above.

Comment: @alfasin: its a good idea. or a limited split if the string begins with a digit.

Comment: Sorry guys. It's hard to explain. I included a picture maybe that will help picture what I'm trying to do. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/T91U3Xr.png) @RonRosenfeld I will look at that. Thanks.

Comment: Which language is it?

Comment: @hjpotter92 At the moment it's not specific to anything. So there are no limits on regex that can be used.

Comment: @user3624582 If each line contains a phone number, why not just replace the nonDigits.  Your regex would be \D or \D+ and the replacement string nothing.

Comment: Have you checked my last update? As you can see there has been spent a lot of time on testing so I'd like to know if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Last update

The expression below will match at least seven numbers at any position within a sequence containing any of the following `\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.` characters

```
([\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.]*[0-9]){7,}
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nX2lG4/1)

You still need a part of the snippet below in order to extract the numbers from each sequence.

---

Try this one (The previous answer)

```
(?:[0-9])(?:[0-9|\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.]){3,}(?:[0-9])
```

Or

```
(?:[0-9+])(?:[0-9|\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.]){5,}(?:[0-9])
```

Use on of the two expressions from above to match a sequence containing at least seven numbers or following separators `\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kE9wR0/4)

Use the following snippet if you need to match `n` numbers at any position within a sequence containing numbers and following separators `\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.`

```
// PHP
$string = "Lorem Ipsum 348/./34//45is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 3////242/./ been the industry's standard dummy text 23./4-4234344 ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 854-123-5234GDFG printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442survived not only five  centuries, but also the 423/53 45/345leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised +44(45)591-505/38 43in the 19/.056s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with 24/25229999fSFSDFD desktop publis...hing software 787-.6/(54)//7//78/34/234/like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
$pattern = "/((?:[0-9+])(?:[0-9|\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.]){5,}(?:[0-9]))/";
$limit = 7;
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches)){
  foreach($matches[0] as $sequence){
    if(preg_match_all("/\d/", $sequence, $match) >= $limit){
      echo $sequence . " -> " . implode("", $match[0]) . "<br />";
    }else{
      echo $sequence . " -> " . "Not a target!" . "<br />";
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
// JavaScript
var string = "Lorem Ipsum 348/./34//45is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 3////242/./ been the industry's standard dummy text 23./4-4234344 ever since the 1500s, when an unknown 854-123-5234GDFG printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442survived not only five  centuries, but also the 423/53 45/345leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised +44(45)591-505/38 43in the 19/.056s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with 24/25229999fSFSDFD desktop publis...hing software 787-.6/(54)//7//78/34/234/like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
var pattern = /((?:[0-9+])(?:[0-9|\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.]){5,}(?:[0-9]))/g;
var limit = 7;
if((sequence = string.match(pattern)) instanceof Array){
  for(i = 0; i < sequence.length; ++i){
    if((phone = sequence[i].match(/\d/g)).length >= limit){
      console.log(sequence[i] + " -> " + phone.join(""));
    }else{
      console.log(sequence[i] + " -> " + "Not a target!");      
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
348/./34//45 -> 3483445
3////242 -> Not a target!
23./4-4234344 -> 2344234344
854-123-5234 -> 8541235234
2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442 -> 2232422442
423/53 45/345 -> 4235345345
+44(45)591-505/38 43 -> 44455915053843
19/.056 -> Not a target!
24/25229999 -> 2425229999
787-.6/(54)//7//78/34/234 -> 78765477834234
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj It's 7am here ;)

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. It does indeed match the provided examples. But the thing is I don't want to be reusing [0-9] in the expression. What I need is something like this `((\d){7}|(\s|\-|\(|\)|\/|\.])*)*` Where there are exactly seven numbers (not ambiguous) and an unknown number of deliminators/separators.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extract a phone number form a string formatted like this (`2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442`), then it's hard to form an all-in-one solution to find phone numbers from a block of text at this level of obfuscation. Think about a few specific cases you want these numbers to be parsed, and think along the lines of that. Don't expect a single regular expression to deal with all kinds of things a user could input to a form field for a telephone number. If you want to find such numbers in a block of text, it could be a safe assumption that there's white space around it, and we can detect that by using `\s`.

So for starters, we want something like `/\s(\S+)\s/`. This just simply means that whatever we want is delimited by a singe white space at the beginning and at the end. To be more specific that we want numbers, we can use the operators in question - `[]`, the group operator and the `{}`, the quantity operator. The first one allows us to select a group of characters to match, and the latter allows us to specify how *many* we want form any character(s) or group(s).

Combining this, we can create a regular expression to match your first test case, `854-123-5234`:

```
/\s([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})\s/
```

By executing this expression in a programming language, you would get the matched string back as a whole, without the additional white space. S in on a block of text like this:

> I've just got my new phone this weekend, my number is 012-345-6789 with a plus at the beginning.

You would get `555-673-3412` selected. But, what if the sentence is continuing with a comma or ending with a period right after the number, such as:

> Sure, my number is 012-345-6789.

You *could* use a `[]` group to catch this, but it raises some problems, because you can't explicitly say that it must be at the beginning OR at the end of the starting using these 2 operator alone, so you need to make use of the other kind of grouping operator, the `()`. What's special about this is that you can use the `|` character to say "OR", so in our case, our finished regular expression would be:

```
/(?:\s([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})\s)/
```

This is the same as above, except now we're saying that a white space needs to be at the end of the string, at the beginning of it, or both, in which case, the "in the beginning" part will match first. The `?:` is required to that the programming language you're using does not catch that group as something we want to use later, but rather just using it as a means of grouping parts of the reg. exp. together. You can use this method with the other expressions below, but just to keep it simple I'll not be adding this white space detection to the rest of them.

For the second test case, it's a bit easier, since you only have the `/` separating the numbers, here is the regex:

```
/(\d{2}\/\d{8})/
```

For the 3rd test case, you could do:

```
/(\d{2}[./]{2}\d-\d{7})/
```

But for the last one, it's pretty tricky. To detect this kind of obfuscation, we need to know what characters can be separating the numbers that aren't part of a huge block of text. In your case, these seem to be  (whitespace), `-`, `.`, `/`, `(` and `)`. If you actually care about the numbers and not just the string as a whole, your proposed solution might just be the only one. Here it is, shortened just a bit:

> `/(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*/`

You don't need to use the `()` operator for grouping, as it's meant to be used specifically when you want to get part of the matched text returned separately or you want to group multiple parts of a regex and not just different characters.

The regex above is basically the following: `(\d)[\s-()\/.]*` repeated 10 times, without the other elements I mentioned before. Using the `[]` operator to group characters is pretty useful because it saves you some characters which you would need to escape with `\` otherwise, and also, it does not mark the matched elements as something to be returned, meaning you don't get the junk back upon execution, only the numbers. Running the following code in JavaScript, you will get the results shown below:

> `/(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*(\d)[\s-()\/.]*/.exec('The brown fo2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442x jumps over the lazy dog')`

```
["2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442", "2", "2", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2"]
```

After this, you could just use whatever language you're using to join the items of the returned array together from index 1 to 10 to get your number. To finish it off, I'll show you how to do that in, again, JavaScript.

> `["2...2....3////242/.//. ./ ./2./.442", "2", "2", "3", "2", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "2"].splice(1,10).join('');`

```
"2232422442"
```

Hope this clears your confusion.